# Partially Dist-upgrade from CLI?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, package-management, aptitude, partial-upgrade

Sometimes a `sudo aptitude upgrade` fails and `sudo aptitude upgrade --full-resolver` then wants to remove about 100 Packages, because of "dependecy conflicts".

Often I can then start `update-manager` and it offers me a "Teilweise Systemaktualisierung" (roughly "partially distribution upgrade"), when I run this then all packages are updated and it does this without removing any packages in most cases.

Since I want to avoid using graphical tools for this kind of stuff, my question is: is there a way to start the "partially dist-upgrade" via command line? Prefferably with aptitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally also `dist-upgrade` by default. And when it wants to remove crazy amounts of packages, I either say *no* repeatedly until it comes up with a sane solution, or I switch to `aptitude upgrade`.

Aptitude's interactive mode can also be a handy way to get around complex conflict situations (just run `aptitude` to launch it.)

Sometimes `apt-get` comes up with better solutions by default (in `apt-get` one doesn't get the chance to reject solutions).

Answer (score 2):

Often switching to `apt-get` in this situation can help you out. Next time this happens, try `apt-get upgrade` or even `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Historically this wasn't advisable because `aptitude` and `apt-get` used different databases, but these days that isn't an issue.

As always, make sure to *read* the solution that is being proposed to you (especially if you `dist-upgrade` as this may remove packages). One advantage of `aptitude` (and why I generally use it first) is that you get to reject solutions and choose your own if you want to. `apt-get` does not have this facility so it is more difficult to play with if the solution it gives you isn't one you want. Unfortunately `aptitude` doesn't get developed very much these days (hopefully this will change again in the future) so we may have to rely on `apt-get` more and more in the future.

Comment: At the moment `aptitude` cannot handle Multi Arch packages, so there is still a difference between APT and aptitude now.

Comment: Right, that would be a situation where apt can find a solution that aptitude cannot.